# Expand iframe beyond 760px wide?

Tags: facebook, canvas

Is it possible to make a facebook canvas app that is greater than 760 pixels wide? I know the answer is yes because a number of Zynga's apps do this but I see nothing in facebooks documentation that allows for this behavior. Curious to know how this might be achieved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two blog posts about Fluid Canvas apps:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/
2. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/538/

This is the method Zynga are using.